# Can Symbian applications be ported to Bada?

Tags: bada

Can applications written for Symbian OS be ported to Bada?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the question is just how much you will need to rewrite. And this depends on application type and what libraries / functions / interfaces are used. In general Bada is quite different from Symbian OS, so you'd need to rewrite significant parts of code.

Answer (score 0):

It depend what kind of application. The UI will need to be entirely rewritten obviously so if in your architecture data and UI are not loosely coupled, porting would be difficult.
OpenGL code could be ported easily as well as pure C functions.
If you are using only Boost library objects, most of your C++ code could be ported.